# $9 \mid a^2 +b^2+ab$. Show that $3$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

$a$ and $b$ are integers. 
$a^2 +b^2+ab$ is a multiple of $9$.
I have to prove that $3$ divides both $a$ and $b$. 
Converse is very easy. Put $a=3k$ and $b=3l$ and that's it. 
I was trying factorisation but didn't get anything from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $9|\{(a-b)^2+3ab\},$

$3|\{(a-b)^2+3ab\}\iff3|(a-b)$

$\implies9|(a-b)^2\implies9|3ab\iff3|ab$

$\implies3$ must divide at least one of $a,b$

But $3|a\iff3|b$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $a,b$ are distinct,

$9 \mid a^2 +b^2+ab$

$\Rightarrow  9\mid \{(a-b)^2+3ab\} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - (1)$

$\Rightarrow  3\mid \{(a-b)^2+3ab\}$

$\Rightarrow  3\mid(a-b)^2$

$\Rightarrow  3\mid(a-b)$

$\Rightarrow  9\mid(a-b)^2  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can conclude that

$9\mid3ab \Rightarrow  3\mid ab$